# Python IndentationError when trying to edit graphical modeler in QGis. Can it be fixed?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-modeler, indentationerror

I am trying to edit a model I built in the QGis graphical modeler and I get the following error.

```
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

2017-11-27T14:53:42 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\modeler\EditModelAction.py", line 42, in execute
                dlg = ModelerDialog(self.alg.getCopy())
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\modeler\ModelerDialog.py", line 190, in __init__
                self.repaintModel()
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\modeler\ModelerDialog.py", line 374, in repaintModel
                self.scene.paintModel(self.alg)
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\modeler\ModelerScene.py", line 115, in paintModel
                arrow = ModelerArrowItem(self.algItems[depend], -1,
            KeyError: u'SCRIPTADDFEATUREWITHOUTGEOMETRY_1'
```

I added [this script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177398/qgis-modeler-error-when-extracting-by-non-existing-attributes-how-to-avoid-dis) to work around an extract by location error and when i tried to remove it Qgis closed the modeler and threw a warning.  Now I only get this error when trying to edit.  It's a pretty complicated model with 19 processes and I'd hate to have to go back and rebuild it.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: When you say "I added a this script to work around an extract by location error" do you mean that you modified a script?  If so, then it sounds like you need to check the indentation of the code that you modified.

Comment: @PolyGeo  sorry, I forgot the link.  I edited the question.

Comment: I can see the error but *where is the code*? Around line 115 of paintModel. It looks like you haven't finished the argument *arrow = ModelerArrowItem(self.algItems[depend], -1,*, where's the last parameter and closing bracket? The next thing to look at is *spaces or tabs*, neither matter **as long as you're consistent**, if the original has one TAB but your edit has ~4 spaces (or the other way around) that is an inconsistent indent. A good editor like Notepad++ can show the tabs or spaces https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39258979/notepad-view-hidden-characters

Comment: @MichaelStimson I forgot the link, I edited the question.  Hopefully it now makes sense.

Comment: For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  It sounds like the code you are linking to is what the code looked like before you modified it.

Comment: Not really, I can't see any code. We *really* need to see your code *as modified* to offer any kind of guidance. Please copy/paste into your question about a dozen lines around line 115 of paintModel. Don't forget to hit the {} for formatting code.

Comment: @PolyGeo I didn't write the code.  It's the graphic modeler that's giving me the error.  I can't open it to even look at it much less get the code and edit it.  All I did was add a custom script to the model and when I removed it it crashed and now gives me this error.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, I didn't write it.  It's an error when trying to open the graphic modeler.  QGis 2.14 doesn't allow me to see the code.

Comment: It sounds like it's time to start again with your model. This happens from time to time, even in ArcGIS, for no good reason a toolbox becomes corrupt. If you can find the script that model builder is using you might be able to edit it and fix the problem, though, an error in a script shouldn't cause the modelbuilder to crash.

Comment: @MichaelStimson  It's not the script but the removal of it from the modeler that's causing the issue.  I am hoping somebody knows how to edit the model to fix this.

Comment: @brink - Before you remove the script, you need to make sure any algorithms which use the script as an **input** is changed. For example, in the post you linked in your question, the screenshot of the model in the answer has a script which is used as an input to the `Extract by location` tool. This tool needs to be edited and have the input parameter changed so that it doesn't connect to the script. When this is done, the script can be removed safely.

Comment: @Joseph I figured that out after it crashed.  Usually it gives a warning when trying to remove any thing from the modeler that's connected. It should work for scripts as well in case you accidentally try to remove it. Is there any way to recover the model?

Comment: @brink - You can edit the model using a text editor and change the parameters of tools which were dependent on the script. Depending on how complex your model was, it may be easier to recreate it again using the modeler... :)